# Issue with OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, firewall, ufw

I'm using the latest build of NordVPN and its last version turned out to be interfering with Firewall, I have `ufw` installed with simple "Home profile" once I connect to nordvpn the internet is off so if I go to UFW GUI and add the rule for OpenVPN to allow incoming connections in all directions this is what I get:

```
[06/23/2019 06:24:44 PM] /usr/sbin/ufw allow in from any to any port openvpn
[06/23/2019 06:23:05 PM] /usr/sbin/ufw --force delete 1
[06/23/2019 06:22:51 PM] Error running: /usr/sbin/ufw allow in from any to any port nordvpn > ERROR: Bad port 'nordvpn' |
```

If I allow incoming connection on Firewall it reconnects right away and the internet is working fine. What does cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find one solution, next to the rule that I have added before as stated in my question I also added the new rule for the range of "5" IPs for example Chromium didn't want to connect to any host and on Firewall reports it was connecting via address `15.18.9.3` for example, I'm using ufw gui so I added a new rule filter for incoming connections from `15.18.9.0` to `15.18.9.5` in rules section and now everything works perfect. Maybe not the best solution but as far it works.